# Creating a Google HTTP Transport Object for Android HTTP Request

Tags: android, web-services, httpwebrequest, google-api-java-client

I'm creating an Android app and trying to use Google Places API through Google APIs Client. I've been following this example:
http://ddewaele.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html

I'm having problems creating a HTTP Transport Object to use in creating the HTTP Request Factory.  Everything compiles fine in eclipse, but when I debug while running on my phone, I get a classnotfound on the first line here:

```
HttpTransport transport = new ApacheHttpTransport();
HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(transport);
```

```
public static HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(HttpTransport transport) {
    return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        @Override
        public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            request.headers.authorization = "...";
        }
    });
}
```

According to the JavaDoc for the HTTP Transport Class:

> Android:
>
> - Starting with SDK 2.3, strongly recommended to use
>     com.google.api.client.javanet.NetHttpTransport. Their Apache HTTP Client
>     implementation is not as well maintained.
> - For SDK 2.2 and earlier, use com.google.api.client.apache.ApacheHttpTransport.
>     com.google.api.client.javanet.NetHttpTransport
>     is not recommended due to some bugs in
>     the Android SDK implementation of
>     HttpURLConnection.

I'm running on 2.2, so I tried using the ApacheHTTPTransport. I've also tried the NetHTTPTransport, but I get the same thing (classnotfound).

Any ideas/examples?

Thanks!

Comment: Using ApacheHTTPTransport is OK. Can you post the stacktrace you're seeing ?

Comment: If you are building an Android application that needs to work with all Android SDKs, simply call AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport() and it will decide of these two to use based on the Android SDK level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run the Places API in an Android environment using the Google APIs Client, you'll need to have the following dependencies in your Android project :

- M2_REPO/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.3/commons-codec-1.3.jar
- M2_REPO/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- M2_REPO/com/google/api/client/google-api-client/1.4.1-beta/google-api-client-1.4.1-beta.jar
- M2_REPO/com/google/api/client/google-api-client-googleapis/1.4.1-beta/google-api-client-googleapis-1.4.1-beta.jar
- M2_REPO/com/google/code/gson/gson/1.6/gson-1.6.jar
- M2_REPO/com/google/guava/guava/r08/guava-r08.jar
- M2_REPO/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0.3/httpclient-4.0.3.jar
- M2_REPO/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.0.1/httpcore-4.0.1.jar
- M2_REPO/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.6.5/jackson-core-asl-1.6.5.jar
- M2_REPO/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar