# Problem with introducing-google-places-api example in android

Tags: google-api-java-client

I'm trying to use Google Places API through Google APIs Client for an Android app. I've found this example: http://ddewaele.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html and launching like java application runs OK, so I must have a right API KEY.
I'm using eclipse and maven and all seems ok, but when the application is launched like Android app, the emulator runs ok but shows the following error:
The application Application Name (com.ecs.googleplaces.sample.Main) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.
I've seen that answer [Creating a Google HTTP Transport Object for Android HTTP Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210139/creating-a-google-http-transport-object-for-android-http-request) and I have all the dependencies there written (and more, and some of the with newer versions)
There is a paste from my LogCat:

```
06-17 13:58:40.442: ERROR/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
06-17 13:58:51.091: ERROR/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
06-17 13:58:52.272: ERROR/BatteryService(61): usbOnlinePath not found
06-17 13:58:52.272: ERROR/BatteryService(61): batteryVoltagePath not found
06-17 13:58:52.272: ERROR/BatteryService(61): batteryTemperaturePath not found
06-17 13:58:52.292: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(61): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
06-17 13:58:52.402: ERROR/SensorService(61): couldn't open device for module sensors (Invalid argument)
06-17 13:58:57.061: ERROR/System(61): Failure starting core service
06-17 13:58:57.061: ERROR/System(61): java.lang.SecurityException
06-17 13:58:57.061: ERROR/System(61):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
....
```

Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Logcat isn't showing anything related to the Places API / API key.
The sample should also work pretty much out of the box with Android. The only thing you need to consider is the HTTP Transport used on Android. Depending on your API level, Google recommends using specific HTTP transports.

The Google API client for Java offers a utility method to return the correct HttpTransport based on your Android runtime.

```
HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
```

Perhaps you also missed a stacktrace in your logcat with the actual cause of the crash. Try searching for your application package in logcat.